# how to load an external script with react?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have just cloned create-react-app and have put an external script inside the `public/index.html`

```
  <head>
    <script src="https://myexternalscript"></script>
```

the script that I'm using then allows me to use their API in the console and on the page

however, the problem is when I try and use it in the react app. it says that `Word` is not defined. for example lets say it was `Bootstrap`
inside my react component

```
  open() {
    Bootstrap.dostuff();
  }
```

it is saying `Boostrap` is not defined. but it's clearly loaded coz I can access in the console. how do I use this in my react app?

(bootstrap is just an example, I can't say the actual name as it's private API)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `window.Bootstrap`, instead of just `Bootstrap`. When you simply say `Bootstrap`, JavaScript steps up in scope until it find a scope which contains a `Bootstrap` variable. If you specify `window`, then it will simply access the global scope directly.